# Is there any 2-way(bidirectional) map in Qt?

Tags: qt, dictionary, 2-way-object-databinding

Is there any 2-way(bidirectional) map in Qt? Simple map that implements 1-to-1 correspondence.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is not. The commonly used implementation is [`boost::bimap`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html).